# VoiceOver user interaction inside UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have got a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell CustomCell
CustomCell has a few UILabel with user interaction enabled
CustomCell implements touchesBegan:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
UITouch* touch = touches.anyObject;
    self.itemSelected=[touch view].tag;
    self.viewSelected=[touch view];
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This works good if I don't have VoiceOver enabled, touchedBegan gets called, and the correct view is 'selected'

With VoiceOver on, touchesBegan gets called as well if I do a "double tap then hold", but the view associated with the touch event is of type UITableViewCellContentView.

Any idea how I would go about keeping those user interactions with those items inside the tableview cell?

What I've tried unsuccessfully:
- make sure that accessibility was disabled on the cell object 
- make sure that accessibility was enabled on the label object 
- tried various combinations of traits for the label 
- make sure user interaction enabled was on label

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer

I needed to implement the following methods

```
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount;
- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element;
```

Comment: how do we implement them ? I need to implement voice over for tableViewCell which has a custom label and UIImageView but it never selects the custom label.